# pig: describe in imported script

Tags: apache-pig

Can I use `describe` in an `import`ed script?

I have a script `foo.pig`

```
foo = ...;
describe foo;
```

when when I do `pig -f bar.pig` and `bar.pig` contains `import 'foo.pig'`, I get

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.Main - ERROR 1200: <file foo.pig, line 2, column 0>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'describe'
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `describe` statement to see if that works?

Comment: yes, it works without the describe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The imported script (having macro or not) can contain only statements, but describe is a command interpreted by grunt. See [PIG-2372](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2372).

Answer (score 0):

It's not an intended feature, but it is a side effect of the way macros are implemented.  Pig
actually has a couple of parser in it.  One parses Pig Latin, the other is used by Grunt,
the shell.  Grunt does not know Pig Latin, but it knows to pass it on to the Pig Latin parser.
 Pig Latin knows nothing of Grunt.

Describe, dump, explain, and illustrate are implemented in Grunt, not Pig Latin.  Macros are
resolved (that is, replaced and written inline) by the Pig Latin parser before Grunt is called.
 Since the Pig Latin parser doesn't understand Grunt commands, it is complaining when it encounters
them inside macros.